# Swap if/else conditions/code blocks according to a bool flag

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I have the following method:

```
private void filterMode1(Map<String, String> appToPlat, Map<String, FunctAndPlat> overMap, 
                               List<Merged> merged, List<Merged> missing, String app, String funct) {
    if (overMap.containsKey(app)) {
        String plat = overMap.get(app).getPlat();
        merged.add(new Merged(plat, app, func));
    } else if (appToPlat.containsKey(app)) {
        String plat = appToPlat.get(app); 
        merged.add(new Merged(plat, app, func));
    } else {
        missing.add(new Merged("", app, funct));
    }
}
```

According to a boolean flag I may need to swap condition2/block2 with condition1/block1 so 
cond2 is checked first; it becomes:

```
    private void filterMode2(Map<String, String> appToPlat, Map<String, FunctAndPlat> overMap, 
                                   List<Merged> merged, List<Merged> missing, String app, String funct) {
        if (appToPlat.containsKey(app)) {
            String plat = appToPlat.get(app); 
            merged.add(new Merged(plat, app, func));
        } else if (overMap.containsKey(app)) {
            String plat = overwritesMap.get(app).getPlat();
            merged.add(new Merged(plat, app, func));
        } else {
            missing.add(new Merged("", app, func));
        }
    }
```

And the result is:

```
if (boolFlag) {
filterMode2(..);
} else {
filterMode1(..);
}
```

How to get rid of the duplicate code in the two methods?

Comment: You can play with boolean expressions if that what your teacher wants.

Comment: Can you give an example, how would you write this?

Comment: Why do you need to switch the order? The only sensible reason would be if the condition checking is incredibly expensive, and you could gain significant performance benefits by avoiding an expensive condition check (by guessing which condition is more likely to be true). Otherwise if the conditions are same, the order doesn't affect the logic.

Comment: Write down all ways a code block can be executed considering all of `boolFlag`, `condition1` and `condition2`, then reduce it down so each condition block has only single condition (no matter how complex). For example, block2 could execute if `not condition1` in some circumstances.

Comment: @Kayaman The switching of the order comes from the requirement.
And the goal to write the above in a better way, to avoid repeating code.

Comment: @Kayaman, the conditions seem to be not disjoint, and they are trying to take advantage of "short circuiting" of sorts.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that's the point I made in my first comment. In order to get a short circuiting advantage, the condition checking needs to be extremely expensive. Otherwise it doesn't matter whether you check `condition1` or `condition2` first. Unless the method internals are completely different, but that's not clear from the question. It's hard to get the code to be elegant, if it's redundant to begin with.

Comment: @Kayaman, no, it's not that thay are expensive. It's the fact that sometimes both `condition1` and `condition2` can be `true`, and `boolFlag` dictates which should be preferred in that case.

Comment: I've added the full methods, for the sake of being clear.
The goal is not to optimize the code, but to avoid the duplicate code in the two methods.

@M. Prokhorov Yes, both conditions can be true, so the order of if/ else if statements matters.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov ah, right. The full code clarifies the situation. Let's look at your options.

Answer (score 1):

Using `condition1` and `condition2` variables and `&&` (*and*), `||` (*or*), `!` (*not*) it will look something like this:

```
if (condition1 && boolFlag || condition2 && !boolFlag) {
    .........
} else if (condition1 && !boolFlag || condition2 && boolFlag) {
    ........ 
} else {
    .......
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look shorter.
Must admit I was hoping for something more concise and less cumbersome, but still this might be the best possible answer.

Comment: Are you up-to-date with lambdas?  If so, you could think of passing condition itself as a parameter.  Then you will have a simpler `if`.